# PHP additional BCC email

Tags: php, email

How can I add a BCC to this?

```
$mail_From = $From_email;
$mail_To = $payer_email;
$mail_Subject = $Subject_line;
$mail_Body = $email_msg;

mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);
```

Thanks for tips.
Michael

Comment: $mail_From in mail() is the headers, that's where a bcc would go, see the manual page for mail() for examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained pretty clearly in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Use the `additional_headers` argument, eg

```
$mail_Headers = array(
    'From: ' . $From_email,
    'Bcc: somebody@example.com'
); // edit, oops, too used to using mail abstraction libraries

mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body,
     implode(PHP_EOL, $mail_Headers));
```

Comment: As mentioned in @Dagon's comment, `From` is also a header.

Comment: By using @Damien Pirsy's code there is now in the body this:  `Message-Id: <C03009F8@xdd14.myserver.com>
Date: Mon, 13 Jun 2011 01:26:04 +0200 (CEST) ` and than comes my text under that. Where this comes from?

Comment: @Michael added content-type and MIME. Update answer.

Comment: @Damien I've tested it and the problem still exists. This is my code: `$mail_Bcc = "myemail@gmail.com";
//
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Hello World / John Doe <hello@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: '.$mail_Bcc. "\r\n";
//
mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $headers);` Is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: @Michael uhm, the Message-ID is usually added automatically. Do you see it in different mail readers? Try removing the `"\r\n"` from the last header you append (in this case, `'Bcc: '.$mail_Bcc;`)

Comment: I removed the "\r\n" but it doesn't help. Also the "from field" in the email says "- No Sender -". The fields "Content-type: 
From: 
Message-Id: 
Date: " are now all displayed in the body above the message text. I've no idea why.

Comment: @Michael Not sure why you're commenting on my answer but have you tried replacing `"\r\n"` with `PHP_EOL`. As indicated in the manual, you should use the line terminator associated with your operating environment.

Comment: Thank you guys for all the great input. It's working now like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Use headers to add information to your email (like CC, BCC, FRom, ecc.):

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

// or 'Content-type: text/plain;'

```
$headers .= 'From: '.$mail_From. "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: '.$mail_Bcc."\r\n";

mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $headers);
```

See [mail() on php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) for better details. Also, I suggest using good libraries like [PhpMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)